# Arguments object и Array.prototype.filter()

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, я пытаюсь решить задачу суть которой состоит в удалении из массива всех чисел одинаковых с последующими аргументами функции и возвращении этого результата. В подсказках сказано использовать Arguments object и Array.prototype.filter(). Я так и сделал но функция возвращает не то. Я думаю вся проблема в неправильном сравнении но как это исправить не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    function check(num) {
      var i;
      //num.push(arguments[0]);
      for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {

        return num != arguments[i];
      }
    }

    return arr.filter(check);
  }
 
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const destroyer = (arr, ...nums) => arr.filter(n => !nums.includes(n));

console.info(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

С `arguments`:

```js
function destroyer(){
  let arr  = arguments[0],
      nums = Array.from(arguments).splice(1);
      
  return arr.filter(n => !nums.includes(n));
}

console.info(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

**UPD:**
Используются относительные новинки JS, с которыми настоятельно рекомендуется ознакомится:
[Оператор spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: @Grundy, аминь, брат.

Comment: Ну, а если все же использовать не новинки а те, что требуются в условии задачи?

Comment: @Roman, обновил.

Comment: @Other что означает выражение !nums.includes(n) - как его читать в контексте

Comment: @stas0k. практически так, как он переводится. Ну и выше есть ссылки на справку по функциям используемым в ответе

Comment: @stas0k, если в массиве `nums` нет `n`.

Comment: уважаемые всё вроде понятно, но почему фильтр так ловко подходит именно для этой задачи - удаления из массива всех одинаковых чисел. и почему условие - `если в массиве nums нет n` выведет одинаковые числа. никак не могу проследить логику, где она?

Comment: @stas0k, почитайте что делает фильтр. Он перебирает массив, используя функцию. Если она возвращает `true` - элемент остаётся, иначе элемент из массива удаляется. Вот и выходит: если очередного элемента нет в "исключающем листе", он остаётся. А это только `[1,1]` (единиц нет в исключениях).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант №1

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  
  var newArr = [];
  
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  function check(value) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
      
      if (value === newArr[i]) {
        return false;
      }
      
    }
    
    return true;
    
  }
  
  return arr.filter(check);
}

console.log( destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) );
```

Вариант №2

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.splice(0, 1);
  
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
    
  });
  
}

console.log( destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) );
```

Comment: Я не до конца понимаю почему в 1-ом варианте после условия if мы просто пишем return? Это значит, что мы не возвращаем ничего, что подходит под условие, верно?

Comment: @Roman да, верно

Comment: в первом варианте неверное использование функции `check`, коллбэк для функции filter, Должен возвращать либо `true` либо `false`, в данном случае он возвращает _undefined_, что корректно приводится к false при проверке, и _значение элемента_. Если значение элемента будет `false`, или `0` или любое другое, которое при приведении к булевскому значению вернет false - элемент потеряется

Comment: @Grundy если дописать в условие `return false` и заменить `return value` на `return true`, будет верное использование коллбэк функции для filter?

Comment: @greybutton, да, так будет лучше

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 1):

```js
function destroyer(a /*, ...*/) {
  var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.bind(arguments);
  return a.filter(function (x) {
    return index(x, 1) === -1;
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));

var a = [1, 2, 3];
a[1] = a;
console.log(destroyer(a, 3));
```